# Проигрывание видео с удаленного ресурса (azure blob storage) в mediaelement wpf

Tags: wpf, mediaplayer, azure, online-video

Я делаю курсовой проект и хочу в нем реализовать потоковую передачу видео( из blob контейнер или asset'a из azure , доступ к видео осуществляется по ссылке) в mediaelement WPF. Не могу придумать как то сделать и вообще возможно ли это ? Может есть какие то ресурсы которые стоит почитать. Спасибо за помощь.